# How to resolve warning from Swift: Main actor-isolated property can not be mutated from a Sendable closure

Tags: swift

I've got an application I developed in Swift. It's working fine. A recent Swift release is now showing me warnings on parts of my code, indicating that this won't work in Swift 6. And I'm not sure the best way to resolve this. Here's an excerpt:

```
@MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    private var _http_last_error: String = "--"

    func fetch_cpuinfo() {
        var request = URLRequest(url: _cpuinfo_url!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        // create a dataTask, which includes a closure to process the response
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            // Check for Error
            if let error = error {
                self._http_last_error = error.localizedDescription // WARNING HERE
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

The specific warning is "Main actor-isolated property '_http_last_error' can not be mutated from a Sendable closure; this is an error in Swift 6". I understand why it's a problem; the code in this task block is going to execute later, and there's no guard on the variable that's written. But I don't know the best way to protect it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the new async/await version of `dataTask` instead

```
func fetch_cpuinfo() {
    var request = URLRequest(url: _cpuinfo_url!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    Task {
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            // handle data and response...
        } catch {
            self._http_last_error = error.localizedDescription
        }
    }
}
```

or even better make the whole function async,

```
func fetch_cpuinfo() async {
    var request = URLRequest(url: _cpuinfo_url!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    do {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        // handle data and response...
    } catch {
        self._http_last_error = error.localizedDescription
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also advice you to follow common naming praxis for Swift by using camel case instead of underscore characters like `fetchCpuInfo()` and `httpLastError`

Comment: Thank you, Joakim, this is very helpful indeed. One question: how/where does the variable `error` get declared in your examples? Is that implicit in the catch?

Comment: Yes it’s implicit in the catch